# What is the difference between drift and trend in a time series?

Tags: statistics, trend, drift

I am analyzing a time series using the unit root test.
I am stuck in that I do not understand the difference between trend and drift in the time series. 
Is it correct to say that trend is a feature of a time series, whose average changes over time and that drift is a feature of a time series, whose variance changes over time?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Drift is an intercept(static) component in a time series.

> [image]

c being the drift(intercept) component here.

---

Trend is represented as a time variant component δt, observe the below equation.

> [image]

Trend being a time variant increase or decreases over time, so your statement of changing average is true.

I hope this clears your doubt between the two!

Comment: Any source for these?